# Cannot access bugzilla from apache

Tags: apache-httpd, bugzilla

I installed bugzilla and added the following code to `httpd.conf` to access it from my browser

```
<Directory /var/www/html/bugzilla>
  AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
  Options +Indexes +ExecCGI
  DirectoryIndex index.cgi
  AllowOverride Limit
</Directory>
```

But if I try to access it from browser I'm getting the following error

```
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
```

Comment: Anything useful in the apache error log? The cgi script is probably erroring out before giving Apache any html to display.

Comment: @JeffSchaller 
`[Tue May 31 15:33:26 2016] [error] [client] (13)Permission denied: access to /bugzilla/t/index.html denied
[Tue May 31 15:33:26 2016] [error] [client] (13)Permission denied: access to /bugzilla/t/index.html.var denied`
I'm getting this error

Comment: try navigating first to `/bugzilla/admin.cgi`.

Comment: @meuh tried and getting the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with `.htaccess` file in bugzilla directory.

Added the following code to the file and restarted the apache,

```
<FilesMatch (\.pm|\.pl|\.tmpl|localconfig.*)$>
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Now it is working fine.